# how to determine the cloudera minor release in the one click install debian package ? (i.e., 5.1 ? 5.2 ?)

Tags: hadoop, installation, cloudera

I've managed to get cloudera single node hadoop cluster up and running from this package: http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/one-click-install/precise/amd64/cdh5-repository_1.0_all.deb

my colleagues asked me what minor release of cloudera this is installing..  and i am stumped as to which.   Is there some info, readme, config or license file that gives this information for cloudera hadoop distros once they are installed ?

Or maybe someone just knows which minor release the above URL will install  (if you could provide that info along with a link to a documentation source that would be fantastic.)
thanks in advance
 -chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one-click install repo currently points to the latest Cloudera version, which is 5.3.0 as of earlier this week.

To check the version you installed, just list the package name. There should be some version number like '5.2.x' appended to the package name. An example command:

```
dpkg -l | grep 'cloudera'
```

Comment: Nice, thanks  !    the only thing i had to change was the  search string.  I needed to specify 'cdh', not 'cloudera'.   This worked for me:     >>    dpkg -l  | grep cdh